# Loading ViewComponent data on demand in an asp.net core razor page with multiple tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am looking to create a razor page that has multiple bootstrap tabs on it.

Razor page: Customers/Edit.cshtml
Tabs on page: [Customer Info] [Contacts] [Orders]

Based on research that I did I believe ViewComponents or Partial Views will be my friend here for breaking out each section into having it's own model and having reusability.

However, I am a bit confused on how to avoid loading all of the data for Customer Info, Contacts, Orders all at the same time from the Customers/Edit Page Model.

My goal is to make it so when a tab is clicked the data is loaded.

Comment: unless your tabs trigger a page reload, you'll probably have to do this via JavaScript and load data on tab click

Answer (score 0):

In both MVC and Core I use various methods depending on how I see the application at the time.

If you have everything in one view model then the bootstrap tabs just show what is already rendered to the client. If you need editing within every tab then this method works well (where data overhead is not large). I might use a number of actions that take the view model but handle only the functionality of one tab. It is also worth adding an action parameter that lets you select the visible tab when the view is rendered. The SAVE option can be simple with one business layer method to handle both the create and update scenarios.

If there is just display of data and links to elsewhere I might use the javascript method to load the HTML of each tab when it is activated from the associated action. If you want to perform change operations then you will have to manage this within each tab. The main view is very simple with DIV placeholders to contain the HTML rendered from each action for each tab. You are likely to use javascript for the update action but you can also use a standard form/post with an ajax helper to render just the DIV content required from the update action.

I sometimes use a Bootstrap dialog for updates which is controlled from javascript. In these cases my update actions return JSON with a Boolean to indicate pass/fail and so the returned message is either an error message or a success message. JavaScript is used to update the tab content on success

Neither method is better than the other

Comment: I see, what I was trying to figure out is if there was a way with just pure asp.net core and razor to load on demand. But based on what you are saying it is either I load it all at once in a single view model or even in multiple view models and show/hide the data as necessary. But if there is large amounts of data on each tab I guess the only way is with Javascript/jQueryAJAX. Make sense?

Comment: You can use a small amount of javascript with an ajax call or an Ajax.BeginForm control. Have a look at an anser I gave on thos a few months back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527536/how-do-i-post-back-data-from-a-partial-view-in-mvc/52538181?noredirect=1#comment92057035_52538181